# Offline downloads for VLC player

Tags: downloads, offline

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 installation running without internet. I have a windows PC having access to Internet. How can I download VLC Player in a the windows PC and install in ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Ubuntu, it is strongly suggested to use a package manager like aptitude or synaptic to download and install packages, instead of doing so manually via this website. 
**EDIT:** But you can do it via [this (amd64)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/vlc/download) or [this (i386)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/i386/vlc/download) depends on your architecture. On [this website](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) you can search any package you want.

Comment: Thank you. But it is for ubuntu 12.04 not for ubuntu 14.04 and vlc version is only 2.0.8 but not at least 2.1.4. Is it standalone or needs some more supportive packages ? If so please send me the links for all those supportive packages.

Answer (score 0):

*VLC* has many dependencies and it would be difficult to load all this by hand in Windows down. To be safe, you have to load all dependencies down, the dependencies of these dependencies, etc.

Useful links:

- [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/q/974/367165)
- [How do I install software using the Ubuntu Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/q/66447/367165)
- [How to install software provided in software-center via terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/q/268504/367165)

Take the path of online installation in Ubuntu:

First check this in Ubuntu:

1. Open the *Ubuntu Software Center*
2. Go to *Edit* > *Software Sources*
3. Check the 2nd entry *Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe*

   [image]
4. <kbd>Close</kbd>

Then use the *Ubuntu Software Center* or use a terminal

### *Ubuntu Software Center*

[image]

Search for VLC and install the package

### The terminal way

Open a terminal in Ubuntu with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and execute the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

in order to install VLC 2.1.6.

Answer (score 0):

VLC is not standalone package and, as you can see [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/vlc) (x64) and [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/i386/vlc)(x86), vlc depends on a number of packages, all of which can have several other dependency, which is why it is recommended to use a package manager that will take care of this dependency problem. But if you are usre that you've everything you need, you can try offline installation from these packages.