# bin/ld: cannot find -lncurses

Tags: 14.04, wpa-supplicant

I got an error during installation of `wpa_supplicant` in Ubuntu 14.04.

[image]

Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: I figure it out. Problem is I miss the ncurses library. It is a programming library providing an API that allows the programmer to write text-based user interfaces in a terminal-independent manner. 
just install all the newest ncurses library packages:
"sudo apt-get install libncurses*"
This works for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install software provided in software-center via terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/268504/how-to-install-software-provided-in-software-center-via-terminal) – the package name is `wpasupplicant`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to install the development libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```

and please **don't** use `sudo apt-get install libncurses*` or do you need all this packages?

```
libncurses5 - shared libraries for terminal handling
libncurses5-dbg - debugging/profiling libraries for ncurses
libncurses5-dev - developer's libraries for ncurses
libncursesw5 - shared libraries for terminal handling (wide character support)
libncursesw5-dbg - debugging/profiling libraries for ncursesw
libncursesw5-dev - developer's libraries for ncursesw
libncurses-gst - Ncurses bindings for GNU Smalltalk
libncursesada-dbg - Ada binding to the ncurses text interface library: debug symbols
libncursesada-doc - Ada binding to the ncurses text interface library: documentation
libncursesada3 - Ada binding to the ncurses text interface library: shared library
libncursesada3-dev - Ada binding to the ncurses text interface library: development
```

Probably not.