# whay if i want to install the program This message appears . and how i can install it please?

Tags: software-installation

```
hasni@hasni:~/Downloads/android-sdk-linux$ sudo apt-get install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Install what program? you need to tell it a package name

Comment: you missed the name of the program to install. For example, "sudo apt-get install gedit" will install the program called "gedit". :) If you provide us with the name of the software you want to install we might help you a little bit more. (why the negatives votes? this is just a super newbie question, don't penalize it!)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install software provided in software-center via terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/268504/how-to-install-software-provided-in-software-center-via-terminal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided any software name. Without knowing what to install, the terminal will only read the package lists from the software center but do nothing.

In order to install a program, you have to mention its name:-

*sudo apt-get install software_name*

This will direct the terminal to to download the desired software from the software center (you'll need internet for this) and after downloading, intall the same.