# Trying to install KDbg debugger

Tags: debugging, debug

I'm trying to install KDbg debugger to use while I code in C and have some problems in figuring out what to do.

As suggested in this other similar question: [How to install software provided in software-center via terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/268504/how-to-install-software-provided-in-software-center-via-terminal/268553#268553)

These are the commands I tried to use:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kdbg
```

And this is the error I got:

E: Unable to locate package kdbg

I'm new to the whole Ubuntu environment and can't figure out how to solve this. The guy that posted the original question marked it as solved so I thought it would work.

Comment: What it your Ubuntu version? Please note that this package is [not available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=kdbg) for 19.10 and 20.04 LTS.

Comment: @N0rbert Thanks for your reply. My version is 19.10, I didn't know it wasn't available. Does that mean I can't install KDbg?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I also just found it was removed (grrrrrrr).

Turns out it can be built rather easily:

```
sudo apt install extra-cmake-modules
git clone -b maint https://github.com/j6t/kdbg.git 
cd kdbg/
git tag -l
git checkout kdbg-3.0.1
cmake .
sudo make install
```

In fact, I had to install some missing packages (`cmake .` failed for me complaining about missing things) but they were not difficult to find. For example I saw some error about missing Kf5IconThemeSomething and Kf5XmlGuiSomething, where it helped to

```
sudo apt install libkf5iconthemes-dev libkf5xmlgui-dev
```

(and retry)

Depending on the system of course much more packages may be needed (starting from compiler and cmake) – but considering you need debugger you likely have them already.

Comment: The mentioned dependencies are important to newbies like me :)  The cmake dump message not very obvious.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case the package [is not available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=kdbg) for your Ubuntu version.

The manual installation of the package from 18.04 LTS is not possible because of dependency problems.

Also the package is not available as [Snap](https://snapcraft.io/search?q=kdbg) or as [FlatPak](https://flathub.org/apps/search/kdbg).

So you have to choose some alternative like CodeBlocks (`codeblocks` package) or KDevelop (`kdevelop` package).